# Did facebook changed something to sharer/sharer.php?

Tags: facebook, share

I've been using facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php to redirect users to facebook with a pre filled message using the parameter quote but it doesn't seem to work anymore.

We can still go to facebook to share a link but the message is not pre filled anymore. It still worked a while ago, did Facebook (Meta ?) changed anything recently ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/734680371318112/:

> I got an update from the product team, the quote feature has been deprecated, we will update the document to reflect the change.
>
> Bruce

So this has been removed, only the documentation has not been updated to reflect this yet.

Comment: Oh, ok thanks, I thought it might just have changed a little but I get it.

Guess I'll just continue using sharer.php without the quote parameter.